# Change code with 2 for loop in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

I tried many hours to simplify this code:

```
<?
echo '<div class="eme3-left">'."\n".'<table>'."\n";
for ($n=1,$i=10; $n<=100,$i<=100;$n+=10,$i+=10) 
{
  echo '<tr>
<td class="dick-grau">'.$n.' &#8594; '.$i.'</td> 
<td>'.$n.' = '.decbin($n).'<sub>2</sub></td>
<td>'.($n+1).' = '.decbin($n+1).'<sub>2</sub></td>
<td>'.($n+2).' = '.decbin($n+2).'<sub>2</sub></td>
<td>'.($n+3).' = '.decbin($n+3).'<sub>2</sub></td>
<td>'.($n+4).' = '.decbin($n+4).'<sub>2</sub></td>
<td>'.($n+5).' = '.decbin($n+5).'<sub>2</sub></td>
<td>'.($n+6).' = '.decbin($n+6).'<sub>2</sub></td>
<td>'.($n+7).' = '.decbin($n+7).'<sub>2</sub></td>
<td>'.($n+8).' = '.decbin($n+8).'<sub>2</sub></td>
<td>'.($n+9).' = '.decbin($n+9).'<sub>2</sub></td>';
};                           
echo '</tr></table>'."\n".'</div>';
?>
```

How to add the if condition from the third code for the second for loop ?

```
<?php
echo '<div class="eme3-left">'."\n".'<table>'."\n";
    for ($n=1,$i=10; $n<=100,$i<=100; $n+=10, $i+=10) {
        echo '<TR>'."\n".'<td class="dick-grau">'.$n.' &#8594; '.$i.'</td>';

        for ($t = 1; $t<=10; $t++) {
            echo '<td>'.$t.' = '.decbin($t).'<sub>2</sub></td>'."\n";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    } 
echo '</table>'."\n".'</div>';
?>
```

In another version the following loop works perfectly, but when I add it to the code above, the if-condition don't work.

```
for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++){ 
echo '<td>'.$i.' = '.decbin($i).'<sub>2</sub></td>'."\n";    
    if($i%10 == 0) 
        echo '</tr>'."\n";
}
```

Maybe their are more suggestions for improvements.

Comment: what are you trying to do? output a range of ints (1-100) and their correspondig binary representation? (10 per row?)

Comment: Yes, like in the first code should work the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete example but should get you there.

```
<?php    

$ints = range(1,100);
$ints_grouped_by_10 = array_chunk($ints,10);

foreach($ints_grouped_by_10 as $int_group){
     echo "<tr>";
     echo '<td class="dick-grau">'.reset($int_group).' &#8594; '.end($int_group).'</td>';
     foreach($int_group as $int){
         echo "<td>{$int} = ".decbin($int)."</td>";
     }
     echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

[Edit] added the legend (1 -> 10, 11 -> 20)

Comment: Ok, I had also a solution with a array range, but here is `<td class="dick-grau">'.$n.' &#8594; '.$i.'</td>`which is my biggest problem to combine this line with 10 td's with the numbers and their binary representation. In your code are 2 mistakes: decbin not dec2bin and missing `?>`

Comment: @Grischa what are $n and $i ? like  1 - 10, 11 - 20 ?

Comment: Yes, see my first code in the question ...for ($n=1,$i=10; $n<=100,$i<=100;$n+=10,$i+=10)

Comment: @Grischa I'm asking you what they should be, not what you wrote, since your code supposedly does not work and is horrible to read

Comment: The only show a legend for the following 10 numbers. In the first row 1 -> 10, in the second 11 -> 20 etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<div class="eme3-left">'."\n".'<table>'."\n";
for ( $n=1 ; $n <= 100 ; $n+=10 ) 
{
  echo '<tr>
          <td class="dick-grau">'.$n.' &#8594; '.($n+9).'</td>';

  for ( $j = 0 ; $j < 10 ; $j++ )
    echo '<td>'.($n + $j).' = '.decbin($n+$j).'<sub>2</sub></td>';

  echo '<tr>';
}
echo '</table>'."\n".'</div>';
```